# Return ids generated via DATA LOAD INFILE

Tags: mysql, performance, thread-safety, load-data-infile

Is it possible to obtain all the auto_increment IDs created by MySQL when I bulk insert a set of records using LOAD DATA INFILE in a fast, thread-safe manner?

In MSSQL I could use the OUTPUT clause to output the IDs to a temporary table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms177564.aspx

In PostgreSQL I can reserve a set of sequence numbers as outlined here:

http://www.depesz.com/2008/03/20/getting-multiple-values-from-sequences/

In MySQL I can send the ids to a temporary table using triggers, but I can't guarantee that it won't contain the IDs of any other inserts done during that time (even using transactions).

Is there any other way to return all the IDs inserted via a bulk process, or any way to efficiently reserve a set of IDs from an auto_increment field in advance of using them?